# Session variable lost in webapplication

Tags: c#, session, web-config

I have a problem with Session Timeout in my WebApplication project.
I set session timeout in web.config to 1440 minutes. 
but it does not work...

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the timeout also in your application pool, on the Process Model tab--> idle Time-out.